# My GridReady event is not fired when my ag-grid is initialized

Tags: angular, ag-grid

```
<ag-grid-angular 
    #myGrid
    style="width: 500px; height: 350px;"
    class="ag-theme-alpine"
    [rowData]="rowData"
    [sideBar]="true"
    [suppressExcelExport]="true"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"> 
    [autoGroupColumnDef]="autoGroupColumnDef"
    (onGridReady)="onGridReady($event)" 
</ag-grid-angular>

<button (click)="onBtnExport()">Download CSV export file</button>
```

```
onBtnExport(): void {
    this.gridApi.exportDataAsCsv();

  }


  onGridReady = (params: any) => {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
}
```

[image: The error message is shown here.]

I am trying to bind a button event to download CSV file from ag-grid, however I realize my gridApi is not initialized properly, I have attached my code FYI.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/26.2.0/angular-data-grid/grid-events/#reference-miscellaneous-gridReady

The event is `gridReady`, rather than `onGridReady`.

Update your binding as follows:

```
<ag-grid-angular 
    ... other listeners/bindings
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)" 
</ag-grid-angular>
```